# Is it possible to have diabetes for about 9 months without knowing it?

Tags: diabetes

Is it possible to have diabetes (type 1 or 2) for about 9 months without knowing it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

[MedlinePlus](https://medlineplus.gov/ency/article/000313.htm):

> People with **type 2** diabetes often have no symptoms at first. They may not have symptoms for many years.

[Google Books: The Epidemiology of Diabetes Mellitus, p. 413...Recent Trends In Screening and Prevention of **Type 1** Diabetes](https://books.google.si/books?id=sZODtZoWvlEC&pg=PA413&lpg=PA413&dq=%22type%201%22%20%22asymptomatic%20hyperglycemia%22%20months&source=bl&ots=m5eziNcqgX&sig=-Vc1_dQ_lvsbLtSZJ9SFNw0IlFY&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22type%201%22%20%22asymptomatic%20hyperglycemia%22%20months&f=false):

> Mild asymptomatic hyperglycemia precedes by months or years overt insulin dependence among persons with islet auto-antibodies.

In diabetes type 1, symptoms usually develop much quicker, though.

[Diabetes.co.uk](https://www.diabetes.co.uk/diabetes-symptoms.html):

> In type 1 diabetes, the signs and symptoms can develop very quickly,
>   and can develop significantly over the course of weeks or even days -
>   particularly in children or adolescents.

Comment: 'not have symptoms for many years.' amazing.

Comment: Suppose a person doesn't know that have type 1 diabetes. For how long  can 'be fine' without treatment?

Answer (score 3):

Speaking for type 1 diabetes, and supposing that a patient has exited his/her "Honeymoon" phase, the timespan before accusing severe symptoms (hypo/hyperglycemia) is very short and highly depending on **what it is being eaten** and on the **physical activity** done.
 There are several indicators that could raise red flags, like: **drinking a high amount of water** (5-6 to 9-10 litres per day) with the consequent high frequency of urinating (a symptom of hyperglycemia), the **need of eating voraciously** and with more quantities (a symptom of hypoglycemia), and so on. 
 
The fastest way to detect whether or not these symptoms are related to diabetes is with a simple finger stick blood sugar test.

[Symptoms](http://www.jdrf.org/t1d-resources/symptoms/) 
[Honeymoon period](https://www.diabetes.co.uk/blood-glucose/honeymoon-phase.html)
[Diagnostic](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/type-1-diabetes/diagnosis-treatment/drc-20353017)